# Prepend variadic arguments and pass to another function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am having some trouble with a variadic printf-style function that I wrote, which works correctly when there are no variadic arguments but not when there are, e.g:

`do_print("TestName", "");` works.

`do_print("TestName", "Key1:%s\r\nKey2:%d\r\nKey3:%s", "Bob", 4, "Alice");` doesn't

I have done some debugging and I believe the issue is that the variadic arguments themselves are not getting processed as they should be. I looked at some examples and similar questions, and that has led me to believe that I'm misusing `va_start` and `va_end` in one of the functions. The format string that I'm generating is correct, but I'm getting a repeat for the first variadic arg of the name itself and then garbage values for the remaining variadic arguments:

```
Message:
Name:TestName
ID:42
Key1:TestName
Key2:-1
Key3:��-�*
```

(should be:)

```
Message:
Name:TestName
ID:42
Key1:Bob
Key2:4
Key3:Alice
```

My thought was perhaps that I should eliminate a `va_start` / `va_end` and just pass the ap in directly, although in certain cases I call the `fmt_print` function directly so I'm not sure what I would pass in for ap then. That's what I was playing with `fmt_print2` for, but right now that just segfaults and is even worse than the original.

And yes, I do need vasprintf. The code here is printf-style, but ultimately I do need the entire message in a single buffer because I then pass it to the `write` function, not a `printf`-style function, so `fmt_print` does need to do the work of combining everything into a single buffer.

Here is a full minimal reproducible example, which I've been testing here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed for vasprintf */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsuggest-attribute=format"
static int fmt_print(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int res = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    char *buf;
    int len;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    if ((len = vasprintf(&buf, fmt, ap)) < 0) {
        va_end(ap);
        return -1;
    }
    va_end(ap);

    printf("FORMAT STRING: %s\n", fmt);
    printf("Message:\n%s[END]", buf);
    return res;
}

static int fmt_print2(va_list ap, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int res = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    char *buf;
    int len;

    //va_start(ap, fmt);
    if ((len = vasprintf(&buf, fmt, ap)) < 0) {
        va_end(ap);
        return -1;
    }
    //va_end(ap);

    printf("FORMAT STRING: %s\n", fmt);
    printf("Message:\n%s[END]", buf);
    return res;
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

static void do_print(const char *name, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char buf[200];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s%s%s", "Name:%s\r\nID:%d\r\n", fmt, "\r\n\r\n");
    
    // send Name:%s\r\ID:%d\r\nKey1:%s\r\nKey2:%d\r\nKey3:%s fmt string + all args.
    
    //fmt_print2(ap, buf, name, 42);
    
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    fmt_print(buf, name, 42);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    do_print("TestName", "Key1:%s\r\nKey2:%d\r\nKey3:%s", "Bob", 4, "Alice");

    // This is also valid:
    fmt_print("Login", "Name:%s\r\nID:%d\r\nUsername:%s\r\nPassword:%s", "Login", 41, username, password);

    return 0;
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction of what approach is best suited for this?

Comment: You rarely need to put an explicit CRLF (`’\r\n’`) into a format string.  It isn't wrong but it is unusual.  It also has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's required for the underlying application. This isn't going to a log file, it's going over a socket. But you're right, it's not relevant to this example per se.

Comment: Since `fmt_print2()` is unused, the example isn't really minimal.  Should the commented out call to `fmt_print2()` be uncommented? The two `bytes` variables are unused; `res` is initialized to 0 and used only in `return res;` and could go.

Comment: You have `\r\ID` in your format string; presumably, you wanted `\r\nID`.  Don't suppress compiler warnings — the compiler is going to be right far more often than you are.  Especially if you've not been coding for as long as the compiler has been coding.

Comment: To my knowledge, it is not possible to prepend (or append) arguments to a va_args structure or to even just look at what types they are. What, you can do however, is what you've been hinting at with fmt_print2. By passing your `va_arg` instance along with some additional arguments, you can first process the new va_arg before processing the other one. Still doesn't solve your issue of knowing what's inside the va_arg, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That was a typo as I made the example, the original code doesn't have that. But yeah, it should be \r\n, I'll fix that. The pramga warning is necessary because otherwise gcc thinks I should pass it an attribute gnu_printf thing so it can check the args, but if I do that, it complains it can't because I'm not passing it a static format string - it's determined at run time. So this is the only way it compiles.

Comment: You can't do what you are trying to do the way you are trying to do it.  The `snprintf()` in `do_print()` is trying to set a format string that requires two separate `va_list` values to process it.  You will have to keep them two lots of formatting separate.  And then, if necessary, combine the two strings.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium So if I did something like fmt_print2, I'm just confused what I would do for the `fmt_print` example at the bottom where I call it directly without going through `do_print`. There's no ap at this point, and I'd like to avoid having 2 different functions. Would I need to have an intermediary wrapper that takes the va args and passes in an ap, or is there some way to do that directly?

Comment: Interesting — I've not seen that before.  What options do you use when compiling?  I'm using `-O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common` which is fairly stringent.  I'm using GCC 8.3.0.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right now I'm using `-Werror -Wno-unused-parameter -Wextra -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat=2 -Wshadow -std=gnu99 -pthread -O0 -g -Wstack-protector -fno-omit-frame-pointer -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` but I haven't really played around with it much.

Comment: `do_print` IS your intermediate function. After all, you need some function, which generates the first `va_arg` object. If not for that second object, there's no point in using `fmt_print` at all, is there?

Comment: To clarify, most of the time, I am prepending the `Name:%s\r\nID:%d` business which is really the point of `do_print`. However, in a couple rare circumstances, that isn't required and I can just directly pass in the entire format string and variadic args which need to be written to a single buffer. In that case, currently, I don't need do_print, I can just call fmt_print directly. But if I change fmt_print to accept a va_list, then it seems I would need another intermediary function to create a va_list and I won't be able to call fmt_print directly. Is this understanding right?

Comment: Why not use `sprintf` directly in that particular case? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said before in a comment, you can't do what you are trying to do the way you are trying to do it. The `snprintf()` in `do_print()` is trying to set a format string that requires two separate `va_list` values to process it. You will have to keep the two lots of formatting separate. And then, if necessary, combine the two strings.

This code works.  It contains a lot of diagnostic printing which you can remove, but it showed me where things were going wrong.  It includes the trailing `\r\n\r\n` as a separate operation.

```
/* SO 7274-3429 */
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed for vasprintf */

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int fmt_print(const char *fmt1, va_list ap1, const char *fmt2, ...)
{
    char *buf1;
    char *buf2;
    int len1;
    int len2;
    va_list ap2;
    char *buffer;

    printf("%s(): fmt1 = [[%s]]\n", __func__, fmt1);
    len1 = vasprintf(&buf1, fmt1, ap1);
    printf("%s(): buf1 = [[%s]]\n", __func__, buf1);

    printf("%s(): fmt2 = [[%s]]\n", __func__, fmt2);
    va_start(ap2, fmt2);
    len2 = vasprintf(&buf2, fmt2, ap2);
    va_end(ap2);
    printf("%s(): buf2 = [[%s]]\n", __func__, buf2);

    if (len1 < 0 || len2  < 0)
        return -1;

    printf("%s(): Format strings:\n[[%s]]\n[[%s]]\n", __func__, fmt1, fmt2);
    printf("%s(): Message strings:\n[[%s]]\n[[%s]]\n[END]\n", __func__, buf1, buf2);
    buffer = malloc(len1 + len2 + sizeof("\r\n\r\n"));
    if (buffer == 0)
    {
        free(buf1);
        free(buf2);
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(buffer, buf2);
    strcpy(buffer + len2, buf1);
    strcpy(buffer + len2 + len1, "\r\n\r\n");
    printf("Full buffer: [[%s]]\n", buffer);
    free(buf1);
    free(buf2);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}

static void do_print(const char *name, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char buf[] = "Name:%s\r\nID:%d\r\n";

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    fmt_print(fmt, ap, buf, name, 42);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main(void)
{
    do_print("TestName", "Key1:%s\r\nKey2:%d\r\nKey3:%s", "Bob", 4, "Alice");
    return 0;
}
```

The output from it is:

```
fmt_print(): fmt1 = [[Key1:%s
Key2:%d
Key3:%s]]
fmt_print(): buf1 = [[Key1:Bob
Key2:4
Key3:Alice]]
fmt_print(): fmt2 = [[Name:%s
ID:%d
]]
fmt_print(): buf2 = [[Name:TestName
ID:42
]]
fmt_print(): Format strings:
[[Key1:%s
Key2:%d
Key3:%s]]
[[Name:%s
ID:%d
]]
fmt_print(): Message strings:
[[Key1:Bob
Key2:4
Key3:Alice]]
[[Name:TestName
ID:42
]]
[END]
Full buffer: [[Name:TestName
ID:42
Key1:Bob
Key2:4
Key3:Alice

]]
```

Note that this code frees the memory allocated by `vasprintf()`.

Since you try to compile with `-Wmissing-format-attribute`, you will still get errors from a verbatim copy of this code.  It will compile cleanly with your options if you add:

```
#if !defined(PRINTFLIKE)
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define PRINTFLIKE(n, m) __attribute__((format(printf, n, m)))
#else
#define PRINTFLIKE(n, m) /* If only */
#endif /* __GNUC__ */
#endif /* PRINTFLIKE */
```

and change the function definition lines to:

```
static int PRINTFLIKE(3, 4) fmt_print(const char *fmt1, va_list ap1, const char *fmt2, ...)
```

and

```
static void PRINTFLIKE(2, 3) do_print(const char *name, const char *fmt, ...)
```

and in `do_print()`, modify the call to `fmt_print()` to take a literal format (eliminating the variable `buf`):

```
    fmt_print(fmt, ap, "Name:%s\r\nID:%d\r\n", name, 42);
```

A lot of the time, the 'non-literal format' check is helpful and sensible, but there are times when it is counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to allocate memory for your fmt_print function.

```
static int fmt_print2(const char *fmt, va_list ap);

static int fmt_print(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int res = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    char *buf;
    int len;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    if ((len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap)) < 0) {
        va_end(ap);
        return -1;
    }
    buf = malloc(len + 1);
    printf("LEN = %d\n", len);
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    if(buf) 
    {
        vsnprintf(buf, len, fmt, ap);
        printf("FORMAT STRING: %s\n", fmt);
        printf("Message:\n%s[END]", buf);
    }

    va_end(ap);
    return res;
}

static int fmt_print1(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int res = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    char *buf;
    int len;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    fmt_print2(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return res;
}

static int fmt_print2(const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    int res = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    char *buf;
    int len;
    va_list copy;

    va_copy(copy, ap);

    if ((len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap)) < 0) {
        va_end(ap);
        return -1;
    }
    buf = malloc(len + 1);
    if(buf) 
    {
        vsnprintf(buf, len, fmt, copy);
        printf("FORMAT STRING: %s\n", fmt);
        printf("Message:\n%s[END]", buf);
    }
    free(buf);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    fmt_print("Key1:%s\r\nKey2:%d\r\nKey3:%s", "Bob", 4, "Alice");
    fmt_print("Key1:%s\r\nKey2:%d\r\nKey3:%s", "AAAA", 8, "BBBB");
}
```

Comment: vasprintf automatically allocates memory. It works when there's no variadic arguments so I don't think this is right.